# Working for same client under two different agencies at different period under the same job title

Tags: resume

I was recruited to work for company A (big company) through company B which was the local agency and paid by company B. I have held three different positions working for company A. Now company A has changed agency to company C and I have now moved to and paid by company C. The job title/responsibilities are the same as the last title under the previous agency. How do I list this on my cv.

Comment: Chronologically or alphabetically...

Comment: Were you an employee of company B and company C or contracted to them?

Comment: I was employed by company B (Agency) to work for company A

Comment: Are you working for  Company A under contract or through a temp agency? If so I would list company A on the resume...

Answer (score 4):

As an example...

**Company C: Bottlewasher from November 2016 to October 2019**

Responsibilities:

- 1
- 2
- 3

Achievements:

- 1
- 2
- 3

**Company B: Bottlewasher from August 2015 to November 2016**

Responsibilities:

- 1
- 2
- 3

Achievements:

- 1
- 2
- 3

You may want to reference Company A within the responsibilities or achievements sections respectively, or not.